# How do I fix a problem with Linker in C++ code?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile this code and it's telling me that the linker command is failing, but I'm not able to work out why. Files provided below:

driver.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "itemType.h"

#include "pQueueType.cpp" 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<<"\n\nbegin main()\n\n";

    pQueueType<itemType> pq;

    pq.create();

     

    itemType e;

    e="fee";

    pq.put(e);

     

    e="fie";

    pq.put(e);

    pq.put(e);

     

    e="foe";

    pq.put(e);

     

    e="fum";

    pq.put(e);

     

    e="baz";

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)

              pq.put(e); // 99

     

    e="quux";

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)

              pq.put(e); // 99

     

    e="fie";

    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)

              pq.put(e); // 499

     

    e="foo";

    for(int i=0; i<50; i++)

              pq.put(e); //49

     

    e="bar";

    pq.put(e); // 500

    pq.print();

     

    /*

    begin main()

     

    fee     0

    fie     501

    foe     0

    fum     0

    baz     99

    quux    99

    foo     49

    bar     0

     

    */

     

    cout<<"\n\n\n\n";

     

    while(!pq.isEmpty())

              cout<<pq.deQueue()<<"\n***********************\n";

     

    /*

    fie     501

    ***********************

    quux    99

    ***********************

    baz     99

    ***********************

    foo     49

    ***********************

    fum     0

    ***********************

    foe     0

    ***********************

    fee     0

    ***********************

    bar     0

    ***********************

     

    end main()

    */

    cout<<"\nend main()\n\n";

return 0;

}
```

itemType.cpp:

```
#include "itemType.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

itemType::itemType()
{
    payLoad_name="";
    payLoad_weight=0;
} // stubbed constructor

itemType::itemType(const itemType &p)
{
    payLoad_name = p.payLoad_name;
    payLoad_weight = p.payLoad_weight;
} // copy constructor

void itemType::operator =(itemType &i)
{
    if(payLoad_name==i.payLoad_name&&!i.payLoad_weight){
      payLoad_weight++;
    }
    else {
      payLoad_name=i.payLoad_name;
      payLoad_weight=i.payLoad_weight;
    }
}

bool itemType::operator ==(itemType &i)
{
    return payLoad_name==i.payLoad_name;
}

bool itemType::operator >(itemType &i)
{
    if(payLoad_weight==i.payLoad_weight){
      return payLoad_name>i.payLoad_name;
    }
    else {
      return payLoad_weight>i.payLoad_weight;
    }
}

bool itemType::operator <(itemType &i)
{
    if(payLoad_weight==i.payLoad_weight){
      return payLoad_name<i.payLoad_name;
    }
    else {
      return payLoad_weight<i.payLoad_weight;
    }
}

bool itemType::operator !=(itemType &i)
{
    return payLoad_name!=i.payLoad_name;
}

bool itemType::operator >=(itemType &i)
{
    if(payLoad_weight==i.payLoad_weight){
      return payLoad_name>=i.payLoad_name;
    }
    else {
      return payLoad_weight>=i.payLoad_weight;
    }
}

bool itemType::operator <=(itemType &i)
{
    if(payLoad_weight==i.payLoad_weight){
      return payLoad_name<=i.payLoad_name;
    }
    else {
      return payLoad_weight<=i.payLoad_weight;
    }
}

/*
void itemType::operator =(string s) // included only for the programmer's convieniance
{
    if(payLoad_name==i.payLoad_name&&!i.payLoad_weight){
          payLoad_weight++;
    }
    else {
      payLoad_name=i.payLoad_name;
      payLoad_weight=i.payLoad_weight;
    }
}
/*  in driver.cpp, the code:

        itemType i;
        i.payLoad="foo";

    would be perfectly legal.  This operator allows it to be simply:        i="foo";
    It's entirely optional.
*/

ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const itemType &c) // needed to print the list
{
    out << c.payLoad_name;
    return out;
}
```

itemType.h:

```
#ifndef ITEMTYPE_FLAG
#define ITEMTYPE_FLAG

#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct itemType
{

  string payLoad_name;       // your option to name it

  int payLoad_weight;           // your option to name it

  itemType(); // constructor

  itemType(const itemType &); // copy constructor


  void operator =(itemType &);
  bool operator ==(itemType &);
  bool operator >(itemType &);
  bool operator <(itemType &);
  bool operator !=(itemType &);
  bool operator <=(itemType &);
  bool operator >=(itemType &);


  void operator =(string);

  friend ostream &operator << (ostream &, const itemType &);

};
#endif
```

pQueueType.cpp:

```
#ifndef LISTTYPE_FLAG
#define LISTTYPE_FLAG
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class pQueueType
{
    private:
        static const int MAX=10;

        int top, envVar; // discuss the uses of the environmental variable: envVar

        T* myList;

    public:
        pQueueType()
        {
            myList=NULL;
        } // constructor.

        //******************************

        ~pQueueType()
        {
            delete[] myList;
        } // destructor.

        //******************************

        void create()
        {
            myList=new T[MAX];
            top=0;
        }

        //******************************

        bool isRoom()
        {
            return top<MAX;
        }

        //******************************

        bool isEmpty()
        {
            return !top;
        }

        //******************************

        void put(T &e)
        {
            if(isRoom() && !isThere(e))
            myList[top++]=e;
        }

        //******************************

        T deQueue() 
        {
            if(top>0)
            {
                T e;
                int i=MAX;
                e=myList[i];
                myList[i]=myList[-top];
                return e;
            }
            else {
                cout<<"Fatal Error; attempt to deQueue empty queue. \n"
                    <<"Check isEmpty()\n";
                cin.get();
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        //******************************

        bool isThere(T &e)
        {
            int j=0;

            while(j<top && myList[j]!=e)
                j++;

            if(j<top)
            {
                envVar=j;
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }

        //******************************

        void remove(T &e)
        {
            if(isThere(e))
                myList[envVar]=myList[--top];
        }

        //******************************

        void print() // for diagnostics only
        {
            for(int k=0; k<top; k++)
                cout<<myList[k]<<'\n';
        }
};
#endif
```

makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -O
CC = g++

list: driver.o itemType.o pQueueType.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o list driver.o itemType.o pQueueType.o

driver.o: driver.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c driver.cpp

itemType.o: itemType.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c itemType.cpp

pQueueType.o: pQueueType.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c pQueueType.cpp

clean:
    rm -f core *.o
```

console:

```
PriorityQueue % make
g++ -O -c pQueueType.cpp
g++ -O -o list driver.o itemType.o pQueueType.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "itemType::operator=(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in driver.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [list] Error 1
```

I'm a beginner to C++ and I really have no idea what's going on so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do not #include .cpp files.

Comment: Why have you commented out void itemType::operator =(string s) in .cpp?

Comment: in the .h you declared an operator= string method but you have not implemented it

Comment: That's what we in the industry call "a lot of code". It's hard to find a bug in a lot of code, so what we typically do is write a lot less code between test and debug cycles so we can fix problems before we get to a lot of code.

Comment: Bit late for that now, so this is a good time to back up your code and take an axe to it, chopping pieces off the code in a rational manner until the problem goes away. The problem's related to the part you just chopped off, so examine that more closely. If you spot the problem, fix it. If not, add that bit of code back in and remove something else. Eventually you'll have nothing left but the problem and if you haven't fixed the problem by then, THAT is when you ask a question at stack overflow.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to Stack Overflow and not versed with the etiquette. I appreciate all your comments though!

Answer (score 1):

The linker error is telling you, albeit quite obtusely, that it cannot find a implementation for:

```cpp
void itemType::operator =(string s)
```

and, sure enough, if you look at your `itemType.cpp` file the implementation is commented out!

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for looking through my code and taking the time to answer! So I had another implementation of the same method earlier in the code and, preferring to use that one, I commented out the other one.